# How do I set iOS 6 iCal start of week preference to Monday?

Tags: ios, ical, preferences

Since I installed iOS 6 on my iPhone and iPad, iCal shows Sunday as the start of the week, rather than Monday. These iOS iCals are synced over iCloud with iCal on my Mac OS X desktop, which has a General Preference for "Start week on" and which I have set to Monday. How do I make a similar setting for the iOS 6 devices?

Comment: Are you in Europe? Maybe you should check iPhone > Settings > General > International and make sure you are in the UK or so. I assume if this is set to US, weeks start on Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, the region format for Ireland sets the start of the week to Sunday.**

There's no way to override this other than to set the region format to United Kingdom, which has Monday as the start of the week.